# Dont hide a menu/menuitem on click

Tags: vb.net, menu

I am using vb.net and don't want to use WPF.

I have a menustrip having many menus.

These menus have many menuItems.

When I click on any menuItem I show a new form to the user.

When user finish his work and return to the main form he should be able to see the menu as it was while he left the main form.

I mean when I click on a menuItem the menu closes. But I don't want it to close.

Comment: Don't use a Menu then?...how about you setup a TreeView and work with that instead?

Comment: Ya Tree View is a good idea but the users are very much uneducated type. They will find it harder.

Comment: Do you think navigating a treeview is that much harder than navigating a complex menu system?

Comment: How about using a series of listboxes or comboboxes instead of treeview then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will likely be more confusing for your users having a menu that never closes because it defies expected behaviour. You are better off using one of the other controls suggested.

Every Operating System (Windows, Mac etc) define a standard set of controls for a reason - to enforce consistency and predictability across multiple applications. It's why you know to look to the menu to find a command. Microsoft, Apple etc all produce "design standards" documents that specify a baseline for the way that your user interacts with your app.

If a user selects something from the menu and the menu never closes, the user could well think that your application is broken.